# does not name a type using push_back

Tags: c++

i am new to using c++

When I execute the following code

i am aware it shouldn't draw anything at the moment i am just trying to change from using an array for vertex position to using a vector as i want to be able to calculate points then use a push_back to append them.

This minimal example won't compile:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> vertexPositions;

const float triangle = 0.75f;

vertexPositions.push_back(triangle);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
error: ‘vertexPositions’ does not name a type
```

Comment: Please show a complete example; that code looks ok in isolation.

Comment: Umm, you need to have that code, at least the call to push_back, in main.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vertexPositions.push_back(triangle);` is a statement. It must be placed inside a function definition. It can not be placed in the global scope like that.

Move that line into for example `main`, and you should be fine.

Comment: The declarations/definitions a) std::vector<float> vertexPositions; and b) const float triangle = 0.75f; are either statements. Is there a special denotation for statements that are viable in global scope ? Cheers

Comment: Ok, a function call is an expression (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180381/is-c-function-call-an-expression/38180535)

Answer (score 2):

Did you add `#include <vector>`?

Comment: +1. That is the only possible error given the code he/she posted.

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem - the following line must appear in your main function :

```
vertexPositions.push_back(triangle);
```

I created a console application as an example:

```
    // test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<float> vertexPositions;

    const float triangle = 0.75f;

    vertexPositions.push_back(triangle);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: debug session]

Is there something simple you might be missing?