# Is C++ function call an expression?

Tags: c++, function, expression, call

A function produces a result, can be used as argument of another function parameter. So, is a function call like:

```
f(1,2,3)
```

be considered as an "expression"?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, its a `postfix-expression` (function name) with a `expression-list` (arguments). See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2az68d4d.aspx

Comment: @molbdnilo: I'm sure comments can be very short, e.g., just two characters. Here is an example: `//` ;-)

Comment: Of course real programming languages can do it with only one character `#` (yes, I'm trolling too).

Comment: @DietmarKühl It's Stack Exchange comments that can't be short.

Comment: @juanchopanza OK, it's gone.

Comment: @PaulStelian That was the joke.

Comment: What made you think there could possibly be some other option?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++ standard (N3376, §5.1) specifies an expression as:

> An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies a computation. An expression can result in a value and can cause side effects.

Further in the same section (§5.2.2):

> A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of expressions which constitute the arguments to the function.

In short, yes.

Comment: I suppose the same can be said about JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

According to 5.2.2 [expr.call] paragraph 1 of ISO/IEC 14882:2014, a function call is a [postfix] expression:

> A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of initializer-clauses which constitute the arguments to the function. ...